# VK API - Отправка сообщений через метод messages.send()

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

В общем, в vk_api есть метод `messages.send()`

То есть он отсылает сообщения.

Я умею его использовать только в группах, то есть через подключение с помощью токена.

А можно ли как-то его использовать с аккаунтом? То есть чтобы я залогинился в самый обычный аккаунт, и через него отправлял сообщения?

Answer (score 2):

Цитата из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/manuals) по методу [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send):

> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в
>   [Standalone-приложении](https://vk.com/dev/standalone) через [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). Требуются [права доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions):
>   **messages**.

---

Но на практике это совсем не так :) Получить эти права обычному пользователю практически невозможно.

Вот [цитата](https://vk.com/faq13567) из страницы [частых ошибок](https://vk.com/support?act=faqs_api&c=6):

> 15 февраля мы начали внедрять изменения и недавно созданные приложения
>   не могут получить ключ доступа с содержащимся в scope [правом доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)
>   **messages**.
>
> Для обсуждения возможности получения доступа напишите, пожалуйста, нам, указав тему «Ограничение Messages API» и приложив следующие данные:
>   — идентификатор приложения;
>   — ссылку на скачивание приложения, если есть;
>   — скринкаст работы приложения;
>   — если приложение пока находится в разработке — срок, на который требуется выдать права.
>   —
>   описание функциональности.
>
> Отметим, что приложениям, работающим с сообщениями пользователя с
>   сервера, доступ выдан быть не может.

Сообщение с похожим содержанием [постилось](https://vk.com/wall-1_390510) также в [официальной группе](https://vk.com/apiclub):

> Как и было анонсировано, секция Messages отключена для вызова с
>   ключами доступа пользователя.

Comment: А какие есть способы кроме messages.send?
Просто я частенько вижу в вк спам ботов которые пишут всем. И это явно не человек.

Comment: @Fruthy Можно обойти ограничение через `Selenium`, то есть имитировать браузер. Но это довольно медлительно. Других способов я пока не знаю.

Comment: @nomnoms12, почему сразу Selenium? Покопаться в условном Fiddler и то же отправить ручками - уже не вариант?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Отправить запрос ручками тоже можно, Вы правы. Но это не так просто. К каждому сообщению прикладывается некий хэш, поэтому придётся разобраться в алгоритмах отправки (не говоря уже о огромном количестве заголовков и cookies). Если есть время, можно попробовать. Но стоит ли оно того?