# Ошибка "vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [3] Unknown method passed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь писать бота для ВК, чтобы тот отправлял от моего имени в личные сообщения определенные фразы, триггерясь на заданные слова. И если с личными сообщениями все ок, то в беседах при написании слова-триггера вылазит данная ошибка (название поста).

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import data
import random
import time
login, password = 'еке', 'рке'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="76676")

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def messages_send(vk_session, id_type, id, message=None, attachment=None, keyboard=None):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {id_type: id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(-2147483648, +214783648)})

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('Сообщение пришло в: ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")))
            print('Текст сообщения: ' + str(event.text))
            print(event.user_id)
            response = event.text.lower()
            if event.from_user:
                if response == "удачу":
                    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'благословение удачи', 'random_id': 0})

            elif event.from_chat and not event.from_me:
                if response == "тест":
                    messages_send(vk_session, 'chat_id', event.chat_id, message='фываыф')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код и ошибку текстом, а не скриншотом. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Это сильно облегчит задачу тем, кто хочет Вам помочь (потому что не придётся переписывать весь код) и поможет проиндексировать страницу.

Answer (score 1):

Нет метода `message.send`.

Думаю, Вы опечатались и имели в виду [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send) (во множественном числе).

Comment: а где Вы увидели опечатку в этой функции? С ней все нормально, проблема в чем то другом

Comment: @Никита Присмотритесь, пожалуйста, внимательнее! 16 строка, название метода — нет окончания `s`. Метод `messages.send` пишется во множественном числе, у Вас — в единственном.

Comment: исправил, спасибо. Проблему не решило

Comment: @Никита Теперь возникает какая-то другая ошибка? Приведите её, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: нет, ошибка все та же. Исправленная Вами ошибка ни на что не влияла

Comment: @Никита Что значит та же? С тем же названием? Тогда приведите `Traceback`, одну и ту же ошибку может вызвать разный код. Как исправление ошибки может _"ни на что не влиять"_? :/

Comment: Был неправ. РАньше выскакивала ошибка, теперь ошибки нет, но бот по-прежнему не пишет в беседу. С лс все нормально

Comment: @Никита Это потому что Вы используете `VkLongPoll`. Это модуль для пользователей, для ботов отдельный. Посмотрите [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1026857/339283), думаю, это поможет Вам.

Comment: Не совсем то. Смысл в том, чтобы этот бот отвечал от моего имени, с моей страницы, не со страницы группы

Comment: @Никита Тогда спешу Вас разочаровать. В данный момент это невозможно. ВКонтакте заблокировали доступ к секции `messages` (при авторизации ключом пользователя). Цитирую [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send): _"Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в [Standalone-приложении](https://vk.com/dev/standalone) через [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). Требуются [права доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions): messages."_ А получить права на эту секцию для приложения можно только в частном порядке, связавшись с администрацией (очень сложно).

Comment: Получение прав на это через токен, который генерируется, например, https://vkhost.github.io/ ?

Comment: @Никита Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1018964/339283).

Comment: @Никита Насчёт [vkhost.github.io](https://vkhost.github.io/) ничего не могу сказать, не пользовался этим сервисом.

Comment: Что ж, спасибо за помощь по данному вопросу. Вопрос не по теме: можжно ли сделать так, чтобы бот пересылал сообщение в пределах одного чата и отвечал на него?

Comment: @Никита Думаю, что можно. В объекте сообщения (который приходит Вам с событием) есть поле `id`, а у метода `messages.send` аргумент `forward_messages` (или `reply_to`), в который можно подставить полученный идентификатор.